# Keycloak - Deprecated imports in the User Storage SPI

Tags: java, keycloak

It seems that KeyCloak has changed quite a good amount last year.

I am trying to import the `UserStorageProvider` interface in the latest version (20.0.3) but since more or less version 19.0.0 the project doesn't seem to compile since it is not able to find it.

I have made quite a research and after taking a good look I am not able to realise what happens.

The interface does appear in the official Doc for the latest version: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/20.0.3/javadocs/org/keycloak/storage/UserStorageProvider.html

I was wondering what I am doing wrong since my import line does not work:

`import org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider;`

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak just moved this UserStorageProvider into legacy model. However, the legacy model

> remains the default store in Keycloak 19.

according to this [source](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/07/storage-map).
You can import this legacy model manually like [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-model-legacy/19.0.3) and add this dependency. This should solve your imports issue.